# useNavigate outside functional component - react-router version-6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

Is there a way to use useNavigate() hook outside functional component in react-router v6? I'm trying to use navigate(url) inside a saga function. I know in v4 we could do something like this:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
function* sagaFunc(){
 history.push(url)
}
```